# In python convert seconds from 1970 to hours since 1900

Tags: python, datetime, format

Have two data sets with different time format. One in epcoh time, seconds from 1/1/1970, and the other hours since 1/1/1900. Need to convert the first to the second one. How can I do that in python ?

Thanks

Comment: So you want hours from 1/1/1970?

Comment: You'll first need a stable definition of when "1/1/1900" was exactly. Does that mean Jan 1st 1900 0am *Greenwich Mean Time*? Or something else? Otherwise you'll have a hard time pinning down exactly how many hours ago that was.

Comment: I need hours since  Jan 1st 1900 at 0am. First data set is from seismic where the convention is to use seconds from Jan. 1st 1970 0am, second data set is atmospheric where the convention is to use hours from Jan. 1st 0am. Both UTC.

Comment: Since UTC was only established in the 60s, that's somewhat… unclear?! Does that mean they counted backwards to before the established date of UTC?

Comment: Indeed, the `time` in many climate and atmospheric datasets have `time:units = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0"` and it is meant in UTC. In this sense the question is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

So, for starters, here are the necessary tools:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
```

Then you need to establish the starting time:

```
atmos_epoch = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Then you can work with deltas to that time:

```
>>> d = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - atmos_epoch
>>> d
datetime.timedelta(days=43893, seconds=28215, microseconds=982930)
>>> d.total_seconds() / 60 / 60
1053439.8377730362
```

That last value is the difference in hours.

You can add deltas to that epoch timestamp:

```
>>> atmos_epoch + timedelta(hours=1000000)
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 29, 16, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

The other thing you talk about, seconds since 1970, are simply UNIX timestamps, which you can work with easily:

```
>>> datetime.now().timestamp()
1583395060.91666
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1500000000)
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 14, 4, 40)
```

Now you have a way to convert from both values to `datetime` objects and from `datetime` objects to either value.

Comment: Great. Thanks very much.